# Why is .readlines() making a list of individual characters?

Tags: python, list, io, split

I have a text file of this format:

```
EFF   3500.  GRAVITY 0.00000  SDSC GRID  [+0.0]   VTURB 2.0 KM/S    L/H 1.25                            
  wl(nm)    Inu(ergs/cm**2/s/hz/ster) for 17 mu in 1221 frequency intervals
            1.000   .900  .800  .700  .600  .500  .400  .300  .250  .200  .150  .125  .100  .075  .050  .025  .010
    9.09 0.000E+00     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    9.35 0.000E+00     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    9.61 0.000E+00     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    9.77 0.000E+00     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    9.96 0.000E+00     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
   10.20 0.000E+00     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
   10.38 0.000E+00     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0

...more numbers
```

I'm trying to make it so `File[0][0]` will print the word "EFF" and so on.

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from math import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print 'Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.'
print 'Argument List:', str(sys.argv)

z = np.array(sys.argv)          #store all of the file names into array

i = len(sys.argv)           #the length of the filenames array

File = open(str(z[1])).readlines()  #load spectrum file 

for n in range(0, len(File)):
    File[n].split()

for n in range(0, len(File[1])):
    print File[1][n]
```

However,it keeps outputting individual characters as if each list index is a single character. This includes whitespace too. I have split() in a loop because if I put readlines().split() it gives an error.

Output:

```
    E
    F
    F



    3
    5
    0
    0
    .


    G
    R
    A
    V
    I

...ect
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you calling `.readlines()`?

Comment: What is the `File` object there?  Python file objects don't support `len`.

Comment: At the very beginning of the script.

File = open("ip00k2new.pck").readlines() #load spectrum file

Comment: Python strings are immutable hence the first loop you are doing is completely useless and the second loop is looping on the characters in the lines.

Comment: Aside: `File = open(str(z[1])).readlines()` defers closing the file until the garbage collector gets around to it. Try `with open(str(z[1])) as f: File = f.readlines()` to ensure an immediate close.

Comment: Also I think one should avoid using `readlines` if you don't know that the file will be "small" and you need really good performances(in time). Simply iterating over the file is usually better and more memory efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> text = """some
... multiline
... text
... """
>>> lines = text.splitlines()
>>> for i in range(len(lines)):
...     lines[i].split()  # split *returns* the list of tokens
...                       # it does *not* modify the string inplace
... 
['some']
['multiline']
['text']
>>> lines   #strings unchanged
['some', 'multiline', 'text']
>>> for i in range(len(lines)):
...     lines[i] = lines[i].split() # you have to modify the list
... 
>>> lines
[['some'], ['multiline'], ['text']]
```

If you want a one-liner do:

```
>>> words = [line.split() for line in text.splitlines()]
>>> words
[['some'], ['multiline'], ['text']]
```

Using a file object it should be:

```
with open(z[1]) as f:  
    File = [line.split() for line in f]
```

---

By the way, you are using an anti-idiom when looping. If you want to loop over an iterable simply do:

```
for element in iterable:
    #...
```

If you need also the index of the element use `enumerate`:

```
for index, element in enumerate(iterable):
    #...
```

In your case:

```
for i, line in enumerate(File):
    File[i] = line.split()

for word in File[1]:
    print word
```

Comment: How do I do this directly after I open the file and store it in a list? I edited my code in above.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```
for line in File:
    fields = line.split()
    #fields[0] is "EFF", fields[1] is "3500.", etc.
```

The split() method returns a list of strings, it does not modify the object that is is called on.